# Cassandra counting inserts of items (clustering keys) with TTL

Tags: cassandra

As far as I understand, Cassandra counters are supposed to help to avoid cost of select count(*). That works great as long as I do not put TTL on the items I want to count. Using TTL though would make items over-counted as soon as they start getting expired. Is there any strategy to deal with this issue?  Is manually deleting old records (along with counter decrement) the only way for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use counters to keep track of the number of rows in a table, you probably wouldn't want to use TTL to expire rows in a random way.

What you could do is partition your data in some way, such as by day, and keep a counter for each day.  Then set the TTL so that all the rows for a given day would expire at the same time (or you could delete the whole partition using DELETE).  When that day expired you would set the counter for that day back to zero.  Your total number of rows would then be the sum of all the day counters.

Comment: As far as I understand you can't put TTL on counters (or has it been resolved?). So that would imply that you have to track and delete old partitions manually (I literally mean non-automatically). Is it better than doing the same per clustering key range?

Comment: I think partitioning approach IS really better. With single row, we would have to count exact number of clustering keys to be deleted in order to decrement the counter properly.

Comment: That's right, you can't put a TTL on counters, so to zero out a counter at a certain time your application would need to run a scheduled job.  Usually in a distributed application it is not necessary to track exactly how many rows are in a table, so it's not an issue that comes up very often.